# HighCharts FORCE pointInterval (from user selection), pointPixelWidth and pointPadding(in pixels)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a candleStick and Column(volume) chart. I want the user to pick the interval (1m, 3m, 5m, 15m) etc.

The problem i am having is i cannot correctly set the point padding in pixels so the spacing will either vary between the different intervals (pointPadding is represented as a percent of the interval width on the axis). This screws up the chart as you change intervals.

As an additional problem, if highcharts own datagrouping calculates the total points in the plotArea based on the width of the plot (in pixels) and the width of the points. If this is off by one pixel my volume/column chart loses it's last points depending on how it determines the grouping.

It is strange because setting the column and candle pixelPoint widths the same for each gives different results as well.

Comment: Could you recreate demo on jsFiddle? HAve you tried to disable `ordinal` for xAxis?

Comment: Yes ordinal is false. I will look at a fiddle today. But the issue becomes more obvious the more i understand it. Highcharts does not provide a way force width and padding in pixel measurements. You can fix the pointWidth by pixels.. and this will work. But you cannot have any padding between the points/groups. Unless there is some way to calculate it in terms of % before you setExtremes. Is there some way to set the xAxis tick interval in pixels?

Comment: Set tickPixelInterval? But it won't be so strict as you may expect - it will take your tickPixelInterval and round to have nice ticks. Have you tried to use tickPositioner?